# Is there a walkable trail to the top of Whitesky Peak?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

In Ark, the mountain in the NW of The Island map is called Whitesky Peak and is a very good mining location, but can I walk my Ankylo to the top?? Or do I have to get the Quetzal to drop him off at the top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to walk an Ankylo on Whitesky Peak. From the northern side there's a path up to the peak and the base of the blue obelisk. Be aware of carnivores. That said, with a Quetzal-lift it's a lot easier.

[image: Path to Whitesky Peak]

Comment: Good to know, thank you.. I did end up getting an unexpected Quetzal to resolve this situation but seeing that its possible with out it opens up more possibilities.